# JavaScript forEach loop specific items

Tags: javascript, dom

Hi My current working code is below:

```
// individual page elements toggle up and down
const   drone   = document.querySelector(".innerContent1"),
        fighter = document.querySelector(".innerContent2"),
        carrier = document.querySelector(".innerContent3"),
        iconImg1 = document.querySelector(".toggleImg1"),
        iconImg2 = document.querySelector(".toggleImg2"),
        iconImg3 = document.querySelector(".toggleImg3");

// drone toggle on and off
document.getElementById("iconD").addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(drone.classList.contains("innerContent1")) { 
        drone.classList.add("hide");
        drone.classList.remove("innerContent1");
        iconImg1.src = "img/downIcon.png";
    } else {
        drone.classList.add("innerContent1"); 
        drone.classList.remove("hide");
        iconImg1.src = "img/upIcon.png";
    }
});
// fighter jet toggle on and off
document.getElementById("iconFJ").addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(fighter.classList.contains("innerContent2")) { 
        fighter.classList.add("hide");
        fighter.classList.remove("innerContent2");
        iconImg2.src = "img/downIcon.png";
    } else {
        fighter.classList.add("innerContent2"); 
        fighter.classList.remove("hide");
        iconImg2.src = "img/upIcon.png";
    }
});
// carrier plane toggle on and off
document.getElementById("iconCP").addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(carrier.classList.contains("innerContent3")) { 
        carrier.classList.add("hide");
        carrier.classList.remove("innerContent3");
        iconImg3.src = "img/downIcon.png";
    } else {
        carrier.classList.add("innerContent3"); 
        carrier.classList.remove("hide");
        iconImg3.src = "img/upIcon.png";
    }
});
// working code leave alone
```

That code works pefectly but as you can tell it isnt exactly Dry.
so attempt number 2 followed of which i cannot get to work.

```
//select all of the innerContent on the page [0,1,2] 3 of them
const planeType = document.querySelectorAll(".innerContent")
// //select all of the toggle Images on the page [0,1,2] 3 of them
const imgList = document.querySelectorAll(".toggleImg");

//when clicking on each button i just want it to collapse the corresponding innerContent not all of them.
planeType.forEach(function(button) {
    addEventListener("click", () => {
        if(button.classList.contains("innerContent")){
            //if selector 1 2 or 3 has innerContent
            button.classList.add("hide");
            //only want to hide the corresponding div when clicking on the corresponding toggleImg
            button.classList.remove("innerContent");
            //only remove the innerContent of the specific item not all of them
            imgList.src = "img/downIcon.png";
            //change the img of the corresponding toggleImg
        } else {
            //if the div has a class of hide then replace with innerContent
            button.classList.remove("hide");
            //only replace the corresponding one to the button being clicked
            button.classList.add("innerContent");
            //change the image back to orgional state only once specified one clicked
            imgList.src = "img/upIcon.png" ;
        }
    })
})
```

As you can see Im having constant problems now that i have named all the classes the same thing and put them in a List because if i click on one thing that just hides everything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `const imgList = document.querySelectorAll(".toggleImg");` is NodeList (array like object) if you want single value use querySelector.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to create UI and add an event.

```
const buildUI = (btns, id) => {
  const cl = ".innerContent" + id;
  const tg = ".toggleImg" + id;
  const elm = document.querySelector(cl);
  const img = document.querySelector(tg);
  btns.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (elm.classList.contains(cl)) {
      elm.classList.add("hide");
      elm.classList.remove(cl);
      img.src = "img/downIcon.png";
    } else {
      elm.classList.add(cl);
      elm.classList.remove("hide");
      img.src = "img/upIcon.png";
    }
  });
};
const btns = [
  document.getElementById("iconD"),
  document.getElementById("iconFJ"),
  document.getElementById("iconCP"),
];
btns.forEach((btn, index) => {
  buildUI(btn, index);
});
```

Comment: I just get the following error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> on line 11

Comment: SOrry i missed "." in class selector. update. please check now

Comment: Yeah  I have tried that again and it still doesnt work. https://codepen.io/SUGGY1994/pen/VwvdVgP

Answer (score 0):

Or you can work with a "deferred event" and avoid looping altogehter:

In the following sample code I linked the "click"-event to the outer container and made use of the fact, that everything clicked inside will then trigger the bound function. I have to check after each click, whether the target is indeed a "button" (i.e. has class "innerContent") and can then continue to unfold the action. In my code I did not remove the class "innerContent", as this is used to identify the div as a "clickable button". If I removed it, then the event function would not process this button any further after it had been clicked once.

```js
const up="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0a0/fff?text=Up",
      dwn="https://via.placeholder.com/50/a00/fff?text=Dwn";
document.querySelector(".outer").addEventListener("click", (ev) => { 
  var tcl=ev.target.classList;
  if(tcl.contains("innerContent")){
     tcl.toggle("hide");
     ev.target.querySelector('img').src=(tcl.contains("hide")?dwn:up);
  }
})
```

```css
.innerContent {border: 1px solid gray; background-color: #ddd;
               width: 200px; padding: 6px;margin:10px; display:inline-block}
img   {float:left; margin-right:20px}
.hide {color: #888}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
 <div class="innerContent"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0a0/fff?text=Up">drone</div>
 <div class="innerContent"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0a0/fff?text=Up">fighter</div>
 <div class="innerContent"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0a0/fff?text=Up">carrier</div>
 <div class="innerContent"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0a0/fff?text=Up">passenger</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two array like objects with same number of elements you need to use them like arrays not values:

```
//select all of the innerContent on the page [0,1,2] 3 of them
const planeType = document.querySelectorAll(".innerContent")
// //select all of the toggle Images on the page [0,1,2] 3 of them
const imgList = document.querySelectorAll(".toggleImg");

//when clicking on each button i just want it to collapse the corresponding innerContent not all of them.
planeType.forEach(function(button, i) {
    addEventListener("click", () => {
        if(button.classList.contains("innerContent")){
            //if selector 1 2 or 3 has innerContent
            button.classList.add("hide");
            //only want to hide the corresponding div when clicking on the corresponding toggleImg
            button.classList.remove("innerContent");
            //only remove the innerContent of the specific item not all of them
            imgList[i].src = "img/downIcon.png"; // updated
            //change the img of the corresponding toggleImg
        } else {
            //if the div has a class of hide then replace with innerContent
            button.classList.remove("hide");
            //only replace the corresponding one to the button being clicked
            button.classList.add("innerContent");
            //change the image back to orgional state only once specified one clicked
            imgList[i].src = "img/upIcon.png" ; // updated
        }
    })
})
```

so the difference is that it use two arguments in forEach second is index in array and you use `imgList[i]` to get element in other nodeList (array like object from querySelectrAll)